# Bash: automatically add a file to a Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, bash

I am creating a `script.sh` file that creates a `Test.swift` file and adds it into a Xcode project. However, I would like to know if there is a way to add this file to Xcode (in the `project.pbxproj` file) from this script? Instead of doing it manually in Xcode (`Add files to Project...`).

Thank you

**3/05 Update**

I tried @Johnykutty answer, here is my current Xcode project before executing the ruby script:

[image]

I have already generated a `A` folder with a `Sample.swift` file located in `test`, but these files are not linked to my Xcode project yet:

[image]

Now here is the script that I'm executing:

```
require 'xcodeproj'

project_path = '../TestCodeProjTest.xcodeproj'
project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_path)

file_group = project["TestCodeProjTest"]["test"]
file_group.new_file("#{project.project_dir}/TestCodeProjTest/test/A")

project.save()
```

This almost works fine, except that it creates a folder reference instead of a group, and it doesn't link it to my target:

[image]

Hence the content of `Sample.swift` is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to achieve by bash. But really easy if you use Ruby and `xcodeproj` gem from Cocoapods

Consider you have file structure like

```
├── GeneratedFiles
│   └── Sample1.swift
├── MyProject
│   ├── AppDelegate.swift
│   ├── ... all other files
│   ├── SceneDelegate.swift
│   └── ViewController.swift
├── MyProject.xcodeproj
│   ├── project.pbxproj
│   ├── .....
└── add_file.rb
```

Then you can add files like

```
require 'xcodeproj'

project_path = 'MyProject.xcodeproj'
project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_path)

file_group = project["MyProject"]
file_group.new_file("../GeneratedFiles/Sample1.swift")

project.save()
```

**UPDATE:**

`project["MyProject"]` returns a file group which is a group named `MyProject` in the root of the project, you can select another group inside `MyProject` by `file_group = project["MyProject"]["MyGroup"]`

Then the generated file path should be either related to that group like `file_group.new_file("../../GeneratedFiles/Sample1.swift")` or full path like `file_group.new_file("#{project.project_dir}/GeneratedFiles/Sample1.swift")`

More details about Xcodeproj [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/xcodeproj/Xcodeproj)

Comment: Thank you for this! It seems promising but I would like to be able to add some files at a specific location in the project, instead of the root. Is it possible?

Comment: Thank you again, I think I'm all there but I'm still having an issue. I've read a lot of this gem documentation but can't find a way to solve this issue, I've updated my original question if you want to have a look at this..

Comment: That is because you are specifying folder path as file . What about adding A/Sample.swift ?